# Maximum number of both linearly independent and interchangeable/exchange with each other upper triangular matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $h(n)$ to be the maximum number of both linearly independent and interchangeable/exchange with each other (that is to say $AB=BA$) upper triangular matrices selected from the matrix space $M_n({\mathbb R})$, prove that $h(n)\leq h(n-1)+n/2$ for $n
\geq 2$.

I am going to use mathematical induction on $n$, but for the case of $n=2$, I feel a bit unable to do it. Can some one give me some hints to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

We will use the "commutator" notation : $[A,B]:=AB-BA$. Saying that $2$ matrices commute is therefore equivalent to say that their commutator is zero ; please note the left and right linearity property of the commutator :$$[aA+bB,C]=a[A,C]+b[B,C] \ \ \text{and} \ \ [A,bB+cC]=b[A,B]+c[A,C].$$

**Case $n=2$**

The space $S$ of upper triangular matrices in the case $n=2$ has dimension $\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}=3$ with basis :

$$T_1=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}, \ \ T_2=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}, \ \ T_3=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

It is easy to show that $T_1T_3=T_3T_1$, whereas $T_1T_2 \neq T_2T_1$.

The upper triangular matrices of the form $aT_1+bT_3$ constitute a subspace of $S$ with any of its element commuting with any other because

$$[aT_1+bT_3,a'T_1+b'T_3]=aa'[T_1,T_1]+ab'[T_1,T_3]+ba'[T_3,T_1]+bb'[T_3,T_3]=0.$$

Therefore taking the $\color{red}{2}$ independent matrices

$$\{T_1, \ \ T_3\}$$

gives a maximal set as desired. We can conclude that

$$n(2)=\color{red}{2}$$

Case $n=3$. Having done a computer program, I have been able to settle that

$$n(3)=\color{red}{3}$$

with the $\color{red}{3}$ following matrices which mutually commute :

$$T_1=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}, \ \ T_3=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}, \ \ T_6=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}, \ \ $$

discarding

$$T_2=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}, \ \ T_4=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}, \ \ T_5=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}, \ \ $$

The recurrence relationship is therefore true for $n=3$ : ($3 \le 2+\frac32$).

In the following cases, seemingly, with the same indexing convention as before :

- $n(4)=4$ with matrices indices $\{4,5,7,8\}$ or $\{1,3,5,10\}$
- $n(5)=6$ with matrices indices $\{7,8,9,11,12,13\}$,
- $n(6)=5$ with matrices indices $\{2,4,7,11,16\}$

For a systematic search, one should use for example the [Bron-Kerbosch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bron%E2%80%93Kerbosch_algorithm).

I have been helped for this by graphics like the one below

[image]

*Fig. 1 : Case $n=4$: the array showing by a star which pairs of matrices have a non-zero commutator. A group of matrices having all zero commutators between all of them can be seen in the bottom right : $\{7,8,9\}$. An important feature of this table is that they are like "russian dolls" : in the next case, $n=5$ with a $15 \times 15$ representation, the north-eastern part will be this very table, unchanged.*

I give the Matlab program which has allowed to build this graphic.

```
    function main
    clear all;close all;
    n=4; % matrices' size
    m=n*(n+1)/2; % vector space dimension
    C=@(M,N)(nnz(M*N-N*M)~=0); % equal to 0 iif commutator [M,N] = 0
    I=eye(m);t=zeros(m);
    for k1=1:m
          mt1=g(n,I(:,k1));
        for k2=1:m
            mt2=g(n,I(:,k2));
            t(k1,k2)=C(mt1,mt2);
        end;
    end;
    spy(t)  
    %
    function t=g(n,v)
    t=zeros(n);
    t(triu(ones(n),0)==1)=v; % fills an Upper TRI. with entries from v
```

Conected ! https://www.mccme.ru/tg2007/talks/CeballosNunezTenorio.pdf

Comment: Your comments ?

Comment: Thank you very much!